# How to add type constraint to functors map function

Tags: scala, functor, applicative, type-level-computation

I'm unable to define a `Functor` for my `abstract class Foo[V : Monoid]` that have a type constraint. this is because of the `map` method of `Functor` which takes a `B` parameters which is not a `Monoid`.

My question is how and where can I add such constraint ?

Here's a sample from what I'm trying to do :

```
import cats.Functor
import cats.kernel.Monoid

abstract class Foo[A : Monoid] {
  val a: A
}

object Foo {
  implicit def FooFunctor = new Functor[Foo] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: Foo[A])(f: (A) => B) = new Foo[B] {
      override val a: B = f(fa.a)
    }
  }
}
```

this raise the following exception :

```
Error:(12, 59) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type cats.kernel.Monoid[B]
    override def map[A, B](fa: Foo[A])(f: (A) => B) = new Foo[B] {
```

My first solution was adding the constraint in the `map` definition (`override def map[A, B : Monoid]`) but this is not legal because this will change the definition of the function in `Functor` and will raise the Exception :

```
Error:(12, 18) method map overrides nothing.
```

Can anyone please help me get out of this ? any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this a case when you need an `Applicative` instead of a `Functor`? That way you could create `Foo[B]` with `pure[Foo[B]]`.

Comment: This looks like a typical [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you describe your actual problem that you are trying to solve by this code? Your `Foo` specified as it is now is not a `Functor` according to `cats` definition because `cats.Functor` must be defined over every possible type. But maybe this is not what you really need. So specify your high-level problem and somebody might come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problems is that You're trying to mix sub-typing with type-classes. Should be:

```
trait Foo[A] extends Monoid[A] with Functor[A] {
  val a: A
}

trait SomeADT
case class SomeValue(a: String) extends SomeADT

object SomeADT {
  //evidence
}
```

Comment: That still remains incomplete.